# how to design the component in c# then client can be define parameter at begin and whenever they want to complete the operation using information

Tags: c#

i want to make a component that they can use like this [following]

they can define directly

```
myControl control = new myControl("information","info","some other info");

myControl control = new myControl();
```

the both need to be valid;

they can make operation if they already set the value like

```
control.completemytask();  // it's need to working if they declare information otherwise thrown a error
```

they can make operation even if they not declare the value by declare the value when complete the operation

like

```
control.completetask("information","info","some other info");
```

how  i can do this in c#.

are anyone show me the code then i can know this easily.

Comment: does, "new myControl("information","info","some other info")" always have three parameters/arguments?

Comment: @Dog Ears  yes the client can be pass all paramaeter when he initialize new instrance otherwise pass them when they want to make a operation !

Comment: "how to do this in c#" is not a valid question. Try something a bit more descriptive

Comment: you do this because i not know any other good title ! thank if you can !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public class myControl
{
    public myControl()
    {
    }

    public myControl(string arg1, string arg2, string arg3)
    {
        Arg1 = arg1;
        Arg2 = arg2;
        Arg3 = arg3;
    }

    public void completemytask() {
        if(String.IsNullOrEmpty(Arg1) || 
           String.IsNullOrEmpty(Arg2) ||
           String.IsNullOrEmpty(Arg3))
               throw new ArgumentException("Not all arguments are specified.");
        else
               completetask(Arg1, Arg2, Arg3);
    }

    public void completetask(arg1, arg2, arg3) 
    {
        // do what you want
    }

    public string Arg1 { get; set; }
    public string Arg2 { get; set; }
    public string Arg3 { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`myControl control = new myControl();`

Above is the constructor of your class.

`control.completemytask();`

and

`control.completetask("information","info","some other info");`

are simply function overloading...

Read up a bit on OOP in C# :)

Answer (score 0):

something like this should work.

```
public class MyControl 
{
    public MyControl(params string[] info)
    {
        this.Info = info;
    }
    public string[] Info { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved easily with [constructor overloading](http://tinyurl.com/24j57lh)

create two constructors with parameters..

```
public MyControl(string firstParameter, string secondParameter, string thirdParameter)
{
   // store the parameters.. and initialise a bool flag to say the've been initialised.
   ...
   _parametersInitilised = true;
}
```

Alternatively if you have multiple arguments yoiu'll need to use a [Param array](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645765%28VS.71%29.aspx) like this...

```
private string[] _myInfo;

public MyControl(params string[] info)
{
    _myInfo = info;
}
```

This will give you an array of strings to deal with.

And for the secnd constructor.. create one with no parameters

```
public MyControls()
{
   _parametresIntialised = false;
}
```

and then same thing for the 'CompleteMyTask' with [Method Overloading](http://tinyurl.com/27prnbc)..

```
public void CompleteMyTask(string firstParameter, string secondParameter, string thirdParameter)
{
   // process with these arguments.. 
   ...
}
```

and another overload with no arguments..

```
public void CompleteMyTask()
{
   if(!_paremtersInitialised)
        throw new InvalidOperationException("Call to CompleteMyTask before initialiseation");

    //call the overload with the supplied parameters...
    CompleteMyTask(_firstParam, _secondParam, _thirdParam);
}
```